# actionscript 3 and JSON

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, json

I've been trying to get JSON working with AS3 for a while now, but to no avail.  I keep getting the following error when I get the JSON back:

TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert Object@26331c41 to Array.

I've tried changing the datatype of the variable "jsonData" to object, which fixes the error, but I'm not entirely sure how I can parse the data.

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.events.*;
    import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON; 

    public class DataGrab extends Sprite {

        public function DataGrab() {

        }

        public function init(resource:String):void {
            var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(resource);
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
            loader.load(request);
        }   

        private function onComplete(e:Event):void {
            var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(e.target);
            var jsonData:Array = JSON.decode(loader.data);
            trace(jsonData);
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You were correct when you had the `jsonData` variable as an `Object`. To iterate through all the properties of that variable you could just do something like this:

```
var jsonData:Object = JSON.decode(loader.data);
for (var i:String in jsonData)
{
    trace(i + ": " + jsonData[i]);
}
```

If you wanted to check if the object contained a specific property you could use something like:

```
var hasFooProperty:Boolean = jsonData.hasOwnProperty("fooProperty");
```