# How to obtain and push JSON data into Arrays? [AS3]

Tags: flash, arrays, actionscript-3, json, for-loop

so I have a JSON link that contains a couple of nodes (not sure what you call them in JSON) that I need to put into arrays in ActionScript, but I'm still having trouble trying to trace out all the specific node content.

I found a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653514/actionscript-3-and-json), but [the fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653514/actionscript-3-and-json/1653628#1653628) just showed how to trace out the entire JSON file (which shows up in my output window as [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],...)

first node: `{"captions":[{"content":"[hello world] ","startTime":0,"duration":4000}`

My code:

```
private function onCaptionsComplete( event:Event ):void
    {
        //var jsonObj:Object = JSON.decode(event.target.data);
        //var englishCaptionsObject = jsonObj;
        var englishCaptionsObject:Object = JSON.decode(cc_loader.data);

        captionsContent.push(englishCaptionsObject);
        trace("captionsContent = "+captionsContent);

        for (var i:String in englishCaptionsObject)
        {
            trace(i + ": " +englishCaptionsObject[i]);
            trace(i + ": " +englishCaptionsObject[i].content);
            trace(i + ": " +englishCaptionsObject[i].content[i]);
            trace(i + ": " +englishCaptionsObject[i].startTime[i]);
        }
    }
```

When I run it here are my traces below:

```
captionsContent = [object Object]
captions: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
captions: undefined
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
```

What I would like to be able to do is put the content data into the captionsContent Array, and the startingTime into a startingTime Array, same with the duration data.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your loop you use 3 times the variable `i` to access three differents `Object` (englishCaptionsObject, content and startTime) :

**Edit** : i have assumed that your first decode was already good, but that is not the case,
Your captions `Array` is in the captions field of your json data, content and startTime are not `Array`s :

```
// get the captions array
var captions:Array=englishCaptionsObject.captions;

var cnt:int=0;

// loop throug each caption
for each (var caption:Object in captions) {
     var content:String = caption.content;
     trace(cnt+" "+content);

     var startTime:Number = Number(caption.startTime);
     trace(cnt+" "+startTime);

     cnt++;
}
```

Comment: In the first trace I get [object Object],[object Object],... the 2nd trace I get null and the 3rd throws an error :( TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. Do you know if there is a way to see the actual string content in the Flash output window?

Comment: @leon i have modified the answer you were not getting the right field

Comment: ah sweet that was it! Thanks :)